# WP8 Depth Buffer works in Emulator, not on the ARM device

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, direct3d, directx-11

I'm trying to display a scene on windows phone 8 using D3D11. I got it to work without a Depth Buffer (using mostly Windows phone SDK sample). But now I actually need a depth buffer to render the scene correctly. I got it to work with a depth buffer on the Windows Phone Emulator (win32 build), but when I test it on any windows phone (ARM build), I get nothing (black screen).

So I must hit something that the graphic card on my computer understands (that is the only part of the windows phone emulator that is not fully emulated I think) but that the graphic card on the actual phone doesn't get.

Please if you have any idea let me know, I'm lost. Here is my code:

```
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = 
  {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3
  };

  // Create the Direct3D 11 API device object and a corresponding context.
  ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
  ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
  ThrowIfFailed(
    D3D11CreateDevice(
    nullptr, // Specify nullptr to use the default adapter.
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,
    creationFlags, // Set set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags.
    featureLevels, // List of feature levels this app can support.
    ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, // Always set this to D3D11_SDK_VERSION.
    &device, // Returns the Direct3D device created.
    &m_featureLevel, // Returns feature level of device created.
    &context // Returns the device immediate context.
    )
    );

  // Get the Direct3D 11.1 API device and context interfaces.
  ThrowIfFailed(
    device.As(&m_d3dDevice)
    );

  ThrowIfFailed(
    context.As(&m_d3dContext)
    );
```

Now for the depth buffer:

```
CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC renderTargetDesc(
    DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
    static_cast<UINT>(m_renderTargetSize.Width),
    static_cast<UINT>(m_renderTargetSize.Height),
    1,
    1,
    D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE
    );
  renderTargetDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX | D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE;

  // Allocate a 2-D surface as the render target buffer.
  ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(
    &renderTargetDesc,
    nullptr,
    &m_renderTarget
    )
    );

  ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(
    m_renderTarget.Get(),
    nullptr,
    &m_renderTargetView
    )
    );

  // Create a depth stencil view.
 CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc(
    DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT,
    static_cast<UINT>(m_renderTargetSize.Width),
    static_cast<UINT>(m_renderTargetSize.Height),
    1,
    1,
    D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL); //tried with D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET with a format DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS in didn't change anything

  ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(
    &depthBufferDesc,
    nullptr,
    &m_depthStencilBuffer
    )
    );

  D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
// Set up the description of the stencil state.
depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

  ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(
    &depthStencilDesc,
    &m_depthStencilState
    )
    );

  m_d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState.Get(), 1);

  CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc(
    D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT, 0);
  ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(
    m_depthStencilBuffer.Get(),
    &depthStencilViewDesc,
    &m_depthStencilView
    )
    );
  m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), m_depthStencilView.Get());

  CD3D11_VIEWPORT viewport(
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    m_renderTargetSize.Width,
    m_renderTargetSize.Height
    );

  m_d3dContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
```

And finally just before drawing:

```
const float midnightBlue[] = { 245.0f/255.0f, 241.0/255.0f, 196.0f/255.0f, 1.000f };
    m_d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(
        m_renderTargetView.Get(),
        midnightBlue
        );

  m_d3dContext->ClearDepthStencilView(
        m_depthStencilView.Get(),
        D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH,
        1.0f,
        0
        );

  m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), m_depthStencilView.Get()); //This only works in the Emulator.
  //m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), nullptr); This works fine but doesn't use the Depth buffer, so the scene is not very good.
```

Comment: Try a 16-bit Z-Buffer format, the 24-bit format is not supported on a lot of cards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that but I have the same results.

Comment: Did you try DXGI_FORMAT_D16_UNORM for texformat/DSV ? I don't think 9_3 guarantees 32bit depth formats, I actually have comments in my own code that say DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT is not supported on FS < 10_0 :)